# SOAP +XML - Response in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, xml-parsing, soap-client

I am trying to get soap response from URL,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:int="http://service.com/integration/">
   <soap:Header>
      <int:Options>
         <int:UpdateLastModified>true</int:UpdateLastModified>
      </int:Options>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <int:Execute>
         <int:commandRequest xsi:type="int:TaskCreateCommand" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <int:TaskOrder>
               <int:TypeCategory>Request</int:TypeCategory>
               <int:Customer>
                  <int:Id>83</int:Id>
               </int:Customer>
               <int:Items>
                  <int:WoItem>
                     <int:Task>
                        <int:Id>16519</int:Id>
                     </int:Task>
                     <int:Comment>New Task 1</int:Comment>
                  </int:WoItem>
               </int:Items>
            </int:TaskOrder>
         </int:commandRequest>
      </int:Execute>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Code I have tried :

```
String url = "http://url.com/wsdk/thatService.asmx";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/soap+xml");
String xml = ""; //input that above xml 
con.setDoOutput(true);
System.out.println(xml);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(xml);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
System.out.println(responseStatus);
```

OP :

```
Internal Server Error
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
```

But If I run this in POSTMAN then it gives exact OP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ExecuteResponse xmlns="http://service.com/integration/">
            <ExecuteResult xsi:type="TaskResponse">
                <Task>
                    <Id>12367</Id>
                    <ConcurrencyId>1</ConcurrencyId>
                    <Number>KLMNOU</Number>
                    <TypeCategory>Request</TypeCategory>
                </Task>
            </ExecuteResult>
        </ExecuteResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

where Am I doing a mistake? Same input working fine in POSTMAN but not working using code!

I have given Content-type : application/soap+xml in both side. Still its not working. I am wondering what makes this issue?

Comment: You can intercept request with wireshark, set filter to http and tcp.port and check they those 2 request differ

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of potential problems here, but I suspect the issue is that you're using `DataOutputStream.writeBytes(String)`, which according to the documentation says the following:

> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits.

I'll bet the server doesn't understand whatever character set (if any) your data looks like on its end. Try `OutputStreamWriter.write(String)` instead:

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
wr.write(xml);
```